# Compilation of Qt Property Browser

Tags: qt

I am using Qt 4 (the latest GPL version released by Nokia)

I download Qt Property Browser from [doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/index.html](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/index.html)

I am using VC++ 2008, with Qt Visual Studio Add-In Installed.

I try to build simple project, under qtpropertybrowser solution.

Here is the error message I obtained :

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: simple, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'simple', configuration 'Release|Win32'
1>Moc'ing qtpropertybrowserutils_p.h...
1>RCC ..\..\src\qtpropertybrowser.qrc
1>MOC ..\..\src\qtvariantproperty.h
1>MOC ..\..\src\qtpropertybrowser.h
1>MOC ..\..\src\qtgroupboxpropertybrowser.h
1>MOC ..\..\src\qtbuttonpropertybrowser.h
1>MOC ..\..\src\qttreepropertybrowser.h
1>MOC ..\..\src\qtpropertymanager.h
1>MOC ..\..\src\qteditorfactory.h
1>Compiling...
1>qrc_qtpropertybrowser.cpp
1>qtvariantproperty.cpp
1>qttreepropertybrowser.cpp
1>..\..\src\qttreepropertybrowser.cpp(1091) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qttreepropertybrowser.moc': No such file or directory
1>qtpropertymanager.cpp
1>..\..\src\qtpropertymanager.cpp(6470) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qtpropertymanager.moc': No such file or directory
1>qtpropertybrowserutils.cpp
1>qtpropertybrowser.cpp
1>qtgroupboxpropertybrowser.cpp
1>qteditorfactory.cpp
1>..\..\src\qteditorfactory.cpp(2592) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qteditorfactory.moc': No such file or directory
1>qtbuttonpropertybrowser.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\yan-cheng.cheok\Desktop\qtpropertybrowser-2.5-opensource\qtpropertybrowser-2.5-opensource\examples\simple\release\BuildLog.htm"
1>simple - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any suggestion to pass the compilation will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I got it to compile without too much trouble. Of course, I've been developing on linux, so my environment is quite different from yours. I assume you DL'd the LGPL (opensource) version, and followed to installation instructions. I think I had to move some of the src/header files around so that I could easily include them.

Comment: *.moc file are not being generated. May I know does your *.moc file being generated? If yes, how you generated them? Do you mind to send me copies of your 3 moc files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Finally I figure out the workaround, I need to manually run the following command before clicking on the build all button.

```
moc qttreepropertybrowser > qttreepropertybrowser.moc
moc qtpropertymanager > qtpropertymanager.moc
moc qteditorfactory > qteditorfactory.moc
```

Not sure why. Qt people should include these command in their build file :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct method. It will make mocking work from Visual Studio. 
For e.g. to get moc file for "spell_checker.h"

I did following steps.

Right click on the header file -> Properties -> Custom Build Step -> General ->

```
Command Line = "$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe"  -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DNDEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SCRIPT_LIB -I".\GeneratedFiles\." -I"$(QTDIR)\include\." -I".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\." -I".\." -I"$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore\." -I"$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui\." -I"$(QTDIR)\include\QtScript\." ".\spell_checker.h" -o ".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_spell_checker.cpp"

Description = Moc'ing spell_checker.h...

Outputs = ".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\spell_checker.cpp"

additional dependencies = "$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe";.\spell_checker.h
```